# Can't Resize UIViewController After Presenting Over UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a UIViewController that I would like to display over top of my UITabBarController kind of like a custom UIAlertView. The problem is that, when I present the UIViewController, I'm unable to resize its view to fit whatever screen is currently being used. The UIViewController (ShareViewController is its name) is designed using a .xib file, and it's currently using iPhone 5 screen height. I basically just want to resize its UIView (view) if the app is being run on any device, but it won't work when I call setFrame.

Here is some code:

```
ShareViewController * svc = [[ShareViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShareViewController" bundle:nil];
self.tabBarController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self.tabBarController presentViewController:svc animated:NO completion:nil];
[svc.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
```

I use the "UIModalPresentationCurrentContext" setting so I can show the ShareViewController with a transparent background. So, when I run this code the ShareViewController just gets added but goes off screen because it is still at the iPhone 5 display height.

What can I do to resize my ShareViewController's main view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave the group of buttons a container which I then translated upwards depending on the screen center. This is a bit of a hack fix but I think there is a better way to implement this custom UIViewController anyway.

Comment: Have you found a better way? Has iOS 8 changed anything for you with this?

Comment: Wow, sorry for missing your comment. No I didn't find a new way, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of presentviewcontroller better make it as addsubview and apply animation like present modal view controller

Comment: That didn't seem to make a difference when I tried. However, I realized later that I could give the group of buttons a container view which I can just move up instead of trying to re-size everything. It is a quick dirty fix, but it works. Thanks.